# SQL: select rows where sum of a column satisfies a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

on [mytable] :

```
[id] AS INT -- UNIQUE
[price] AS MONEY
```

on a set which is ordered by [id], i need to select those [id]s where the sum of [price] meets some condition

for example:

```
[id]    [price]
   1       2.0
   2       4.7
   3       3.2
   4       2.8
   5       6.2
   6       1.5
   7       4.2
   8       3.3
```

for a given number '10.0':

```
[id]  [price] [r_total]
   1     2.0        2.0
   2     4.7        6.7
   3     3.2        9.9
   4     2.8       12.7 <-- here the criteria meets for 10.0
   5     6.2       18.9
   6     1.5       20.4
   7     4.2       24.6
   8     3.3       27.9
```

the desired result is a set of [id]s :

```
[id]
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

The problem is solved using Running Total, but the main problem is that I want to avoid calculating the running total for all the set first, and then find the point where the criteria meets, and the reason is that the table contains more than 100.000.000 rows, and the given number comparing to the total sum of [price] usually is very small ( eg: 1250.14 ), and the expected result barely riches 100-150 rows!

Is there any other way to calculate and get desired rows without disturbing those 100.000.000 rows ?

Comment: it should be `12.7` instead of `11.7` right?

Comment: yes you're right - speed kills :(

Comment: why -1 ? what did i ask wrong ? Explain please. I'm trying to do all things right.

Comment: They probably gave you a -1 because it is somewhat unclear exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: well i think one could ask more questions before voting ( to me it has no point at all, but if something is unclear-  why not ask more questions to make it clear ? - English is not my native language ! )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using CTE:

```
;with  CTE1 as 
(
    SELECT 
        ID, Price, Price as CUM_SUM 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE ID=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        c.ID, c.Price, c.Price+c1.CUM_SUM as CUM_SUM 
    FROM CTE1 c1 INNER JOIN 
        YourTable c on c.ID=c1.ID+1
    WHERE 10 >c1.CUM_SUM
)
select * from CTE1
```

Comment: This is a really good answer!  I would give it 10 up votes if I could.

Comment: Elegant, yes; useful, not so much with running totals because of the expense and limitations of recursing many levels.  See the cursor solution below.  Where recursive CTE's shine is in a tree-type scenario such as an org chart, where there are few recursion levels.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to believe this, but as the # of rows involved grows (e.g., a large running total threshold), BY FAR the most efficient way to solve this is with a **CURSOR!!**   YES, really!  [Check it out here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/calculating-running-totals).  Btw, the recursive CTE method can run into recursion level limits (like a stack overflow).

Comment: you're right! but i'm going to stick with recursive method, since the number of rows involved for this calculation is near 30-40 !